# UICollectionView selected cells issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView, i am selected cell with didSelectItemAt and deselect with didDeselectItemAt but selected cells are replaced

[image]

https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-2715e62591.gif

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

       // print(indexPath)

        let collectionActive: UIImageView = {
            let image=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "collectionActive"))
            image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            return image
        }()




        if cell?.isSelected == true {
            cell?.backgroundView = collectionActive
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        let collectionInactive: UIImageView = {
            let image=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "collectionInactive"))
            image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            return image
        }()


        if cell?.isSelected == false {
            cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Cells selected on scrolling in collection view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338208/multiple-cells-selected-on-scrolling-in-collection-view)

Comment: I am using swift 4

Comment: We need more of an explanation if you want help. What does your code look like, what did you expect to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: And yet logic is the same and all method used have equivalent in Swift.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also worked on same things, I have following solution for that.

You need to create array of indexPath which will store selected indexPath.

```
var arrSelectedIndexPath = [IndexPath]()
```

In `cellForRowAtItem` method add following code which will check if arrSelectedIndexPath contains indexPath then display selected active background else display inactive background.

```
if arrSelectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
    cell?.backgroundView = collectionActive
} else {
    cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
}
```

In `didSelect` method you need to add following code which also same as above logic, but just add or remove indexPath.

```
if arrSelectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
    cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
    arrSelectedIndexPath.remove(at: arrSelectedIndexPath.index(of: indexPath)!)
} else {
    cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
    arrSelectedIndexPath.append(indexPath)
}
```

I hope this solution work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. In "didSelectItemAt" function add converse condition also:

```
if cell?.isSelected == true {
        cell?.backgroundView = collectionActive
} else {
       cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
}
```

Similarly, in "didDeselectItemAt" add this condition:

```
if cell?.isSelected == false {
        cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
} else {
        cell?.backgroundView = collectionActive
}
```

This problem occurs whenever we are reusing the cells. Above code might help you!!